# Difference between smart contract and wallet address

Tags: web3js, blockchain, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodejs

I have list of addresses & I am trying to find out if the address is **wallet address** or **smart contract address**. I am using web3js. Is there any way to distinguish between smart contract and wallet address?

As an example, let's say I have an address `x = "0x0f3dd2fcd9ff5b8b082db6e39a1b11a579cfdee5"` and I need to know if `x` is a smart contract or wallet.

thank you very much.

Comment: Yes you try to check if there is code behind that address using the getCode method https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart contract address is an ethereum address that has code/data behind it. so to check if the given address is "currently" a contract you can use the getCode method from Web3js

> web3.eth.getCode(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])

If this method returns something then it is 100% a contract, otherwise it is an address of a wallet or a contract that has not been deployed yet (or already self destructed)

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html?highlight=getCode#getcode

Comment: GetCode returns empty for self-destructed contracts.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ismael. This is what I was looking for.